# Eclipse Android Project broken from accidental Run of XML

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Have had this happen alot, I forget to select the .java file before running an android app from Eclipse.

I have a .xml selected, press Run and the projectfile breaks.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried turning it (eclipse) `on` and `off` again?  (Totally, serious!) Works usually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually adds an unnecessary file next to the xml file. You can just delete this file - this will solve the problem. For example, say you have an mylayout.xml file in res/layouts, and you accidentally run it - result will be a mylayout.out.xml file in res/layouts (next to original file). Just delete it. If there's still an error, rebuild the project (project->clean, and then project->build if build automatically isn't checked).

Comment: This works but it's still a pain to have to select a Java file when editing XML. Isn't there some way to Eclipse to build the project when an XML file is currently selected?